# What is the difference between registering BroadcastReceiver in code and in manifest?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

What is the difference between registering `BroadcastReceiver` through code in an `Activity` and in Android manifest? Also, can `Service` be started from manifest, without calling `startService()` from code?

I would like to start all the `BroadcastReceiver`s and `Service`s on boot completed. But, when I reboot my device, some of them start, some of them don't. All are added to manifest and are  working when I build application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the difference registering receiver through activity and in android manifest?

Receivers declared in manifest always active, registered in activity - active only after registration and will die with app process.

> can service be started from manifest, without call startService() from code?

No

Start all services inside BootFinishedReceiver (or whatever you called it)

Also, it's good practice to register only one receiver for all broadcasts.

Comment: Care to elaborate on this to register only one receiver for all broadcasts?

Comment: So, basically, what you are saying is that I should register one receiever with all the intents that I want to broadcast, and then to do my logic from there?

Comment: @MiljanVulovic yes, use `switch(intent.action)` and do your logic depending on intent type